# Alert with password input in Swift OS X

Tags: macos, swift

I am trying to create a OS X app using Swift, and it's been going well until now!

What I want to do is prompt user to enter a password in an alert (or any dialog really), save it in a variable and use it later on. Now, this app is just to get my hands dirty, so I don't even want the input box to be secure. It just needs to popup and ask for text input.

I have looked everywhere. Scanned the `NSAlert` reference, there seems to be no easy way of doing this. In contrast, on iOS `UIAlertController` does this very easily.

What I tried to do is create an `NSAlert` instance and modify its `AccessoryView` as suggested in [NSAlert Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSAlert_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSAlert/accessoryView), but that does not let me add an `NSTextField`.

Is there something I'm missing, or I can't find any examples because it's bad design?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using storyboards, you can create a new viewcontroller in the storyboard with the layout for your box. Then you can for example have this new viewcontroller be shown as a sheet, or a pop-up using a segue.

You can also use `presentViewController` in code to show the viewcontroller in a more custom fashion (using a custom animation for example).

Answer (score 1):

You can use accessoryView to add a control (TextField in your case) to NSAlert.